# I am not able to use the variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to use the variables
[image]

i just want touse those variables in another page in text widget but i can not pass

[image]

Comment: could you add your code instead of screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to simply mark your `_tabs` as `late`, so like

```
late final List<Widget> _tabs = [
```